# Rigid Body collider

Tags: rigidbody

So I created a plane and gave it a rigid body component and I made a Cube and gave it a rigid body as well but, when I sculpted my Plane, the rigid body stays at its normal shape and the Cube won't collide correctly with the Plane, is there a way to fix this?

thanks for your help.
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi , here is the file https://pasteall.org/media/9/d/9da1ef31347fb6fd551b18b17d119dec.blend

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale of your ground:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, what do u mean apply the scale?

Comment: you've scaled your object in Object mode, so it doesn't have its default scale of 1.1.1 which can cause problems sometimes, typically for rigid body it's better to apply the scale (Ctrl A > Scale in Obect mode)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I just needed to sculpt it first then add the rigid body and it fixed the problem.